# How to update a key's value in an ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> in Android?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to compare and update an item in a `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`named cart.
I am doing the following:

```
            cart_list.put("quantity", "" +5);   //cart_list is HashMap<String,String>
            cart_list.put("item_id", "" + 1);
            cart.add(cart_list);

            cart_list.put("quantity", "" +6);   //cart_list is HashMap<String,String>
            cart_list.put("item_id", "" + 1);
            cart_list.put("prefernces", "no salt");  
            cart.add(cart_list);
```

I want to update the 'preferences`from`no salt`to`xtra salt`. Can anyone tell me step by step how to do it?

Comment: Ann, little bit unclear? What you want to do exactly dear?

Comment: ou'd get the proper HashMap from the array list then put the new value in it.  Like this:

    cart_list.get(1).put("preferences", "xtra sale");

The trick is that you'd need to figure out which item in the list to update, and you don't give enough info for us to figure that part out.

Comment: @pratik I am trying to update the `preferences` value in the ArrayList. But the problem is that they have the same `item_id` i.e 1. So i am not able to figure out how to proceed.

Comment: @Ann that means instead of "no salt" you want new value everytime?

Comment: Initially I add the above mentioned values to a arraylist<hashmap>. Now I want to update that same arraylist<hashmap> with the preferences changed to xtra salt.

Comment: @Ann can you please post your full code here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get your appropriate `HashMap` from your list

```
Map<String,String> map = cart.get(n);
```

where `n` is the index of the HashMap in your list (remember the first list will be index 0), so if you wanted the first HashMap in your list, you'd do

```
Map<String,String> map = cart.get(0);
```

Then, you can simply overwrite the previous value, since a key (e.g. `prefernces`) can only map to one value, this will overwrite the previous value.

```
map.put("prefernces", "xtra salt");
```

Note that your keys have to exactly match, and in your code you've used "prefernces" and then in your comments you use "preferences", which are different spellings.